# MediaStreamTrack - set source --W3C Documentation missed reference

Tags: webrtc, w3c, mediastream

While reading trough the [documentation](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#terminology) i got a hint that it is possible to add source from local media(video/audio) file and stream it using PeerConnection.

But the sentence:
**Note that this document describes the use of microphone and camera type sources only, the use of other source types is described in other documents.**

So, does does someone has these documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your pick from https://github.com/w3c/?query=mediacapture

- https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/
- https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-depth/
- https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/
- And of course http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/ can be a source itself.